# Keras 'Model' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to read the output of an intermediate layer in Keras :

```
input_dim = 30
encoding_dim = 14

input_layer = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))

encoder = Dense(encoding_dim, activation="tanh", 
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_layer)
encoder = Dense(int(encoding_dim / 2), activation="relu")(encoder)

decoder = Dense(int(encoding_dim / 2), activation='tanh',name='decoder_input')(encoder)
decoder = Dense(input_dim, activation='relu',name='decoder_output')(decoder)

autoencoder = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=decoder)


#evaluate decoder...
layer_output_dec =  Model(inputs=autoencoder.layers[3].input,
                             outputs=autoencoder.layers[4].output)
```

However I got the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     89                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
     90             # Graph network
---> 91             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
     92         else:
     93             # Subclassed network

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.pyc in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name)
    181                           'instantiated via '
    182                           '`tensor = tf.layers.Input(shape)`.\n'
--> 183                           'The tensor that caused the issue was: ' +
    184                           str(x.name))
    185         for x in self.outputs:

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'name'
```

I thought the error was on the missing name of the layers but it didn't help. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this issue. Maybe a Python 2.7 vs. 3.x thing? I do get an error about an invalid input layer to a `Model` object on the last line though, which is fixed if I change it to `Model(inputs=autoencoder.layers[0].input, ...)` or `...layers[1].input, ...`.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. Yes it works if you put index 0 or 1 but not above. Above I have the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is taking an input that is already connected to something coming before it. It's not possible to have this model working well.

```
#evaluate decoder...
layer_output_dec =  Model(inputs=autoencoder.layers[3].input,
                         outputs=autoencoder.layers[4].output)
```

You need proper encoder and decoder models:

```
#encoder
input_tensor = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))

encoderOut = Dense(encoding_dim, activation="tanh", 
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(10e-5))(input_tensor)
encoderOut = Dense(int(encoding_dim / 2), activation="relu")(encoderOut)

encoder = Model(input_tensor, encoderOut)


#decoder
decoder_input = Input(shape=(int(encoding_dim / 2),))
decoderOut = Dense(int(encoding_dim / 2), activation='tanh',name='decoder_input')(decoder_input)
decoderOut = Dense(input_dim, activation='relu',name='decoder_output')(decoderOut)

decoder = Model(decoder_input, decoderOut)

#autoencoder
autoInput = Input(shape=(input_dim, ))
encoderOut = encoder(autoInput)
decoderOut = decoder(encoderOut)
autoencoder = Model(inputs=autoInput, outputs=decoderOut)
```

Use the three models according to your needs.

For your question, use `decoder` as a model.